# Amazon EC2 Oracle 11G can't query a big set of data from external machine

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g

We have Oracle 11g installed on Win2008 R2 and everything is OK until we're trying to get data from external machine (localhost works good). The issue is really strange. We can connect to the database using SQL developer but once trying to select data and fetch table larger than 40k rows SQL Developer hangs and session is waiting. Small queries work fine.

I queried v$session:

```
STATUS - INACTIVE
EVENT - SQL*Net message from client
STATE - WAITING
```

Any clue appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any firewalls that might be interfering, maybe?

Comment: Only Windows firewall, so I think it's not a case here..

Comment: Is it possible that EC2 network connection is so slow? I was able fetch 16k numbers in approx 10 minutes...

Comment: Install wireshark on the client and look what happens, to see if there is no traffic anymore or if it's just slow. If traffic comes to a complete halt, the last frames before the halt might be interesting as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did it, but now it looks better (connection is faster). Is it possible that cloud is slow during the day and becomes better late evening?